# Google Analytics "Goals" .. numbers seem inflated?

Tags: google-analytics

When I look at the Google Analytics goal report for yesterday, it shows that I had 3,000 conversions for a given goal - 74% completed, and 6% abandoned.

- Where is the missing 20%?
- My numbers show more like 500 conversions for this goal. Why are Google's numbers so different?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot or extended description of the goal's configuration? Regarding the extra 2500 conversions, you may have multiple calls to the page tracking event on your goal completion page or some other configuration issue (in which case it would help to know which site this issue is occurring on).

Comment: I had multiple contact forms on a website. Sidebar site wide, a contact form, and a popup. All lead to the same thank you page, the goals weren't configured uniquely and messed up the results. Check your traffic sources log and drill down to see if there were any unusual hits to your conversion page.

Comment: Have you correctly configured your GA goals?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe 6 weeks ago I set up new "goals" in analytics for a client with a corporate (they are a franchisee) subdomain, which is a horrific mess. That fact slipped my mind (the goal, as pathetic as it is was 2.2 pageviews per visitor), and when I check analytics today I saw what I thought was a spectacular month in conversions from AdWords. A bit more digging made me realize that wasn't the case, but that now my "goals" in analytics included the new settings (oops).

While goals in GA and conversions in AdWords can overlap, the differences are key. As a Google rep explained to me: you can set and import goals from analytics into AdWords, but not the other way around. So structure and exact definitions are important.

More info on the differences between [Google Analytics and AdWords tracking](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2679221)

Answer (score -2):

Google is free and not always accurate. They are not accountable for analytics. I would use a premium service like [Clicky](http://getclicky.com/). Its only 60.00 a year. 30 day free trial.

Comment: -1 Request was for an explanation of the GA behavior, not recommendations of entirely other services. Also: **citation needed**. There are *way* too many sites happily using GA for you to simply dismiss it as inaccurate without backing it up.